# setting an array element with a sequence, it says my list is inhomogeneous but i dont think it is

Tags: python, list, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

i was trying to create a simple chat bot with tensorflow
i have a simple intents file in .json format that is something like this

```
{"intents": [
  {"tag": "greeting",
    "patterns": ["Hi", "hello" ....],
    "responses": ["greeting"],
  },
  {"tag": "goodbye",
    "patterns": ["bye", "goodbye"],
    "responses": [""goodbye],
  },
]
```

first i tokenized them with wordnetllemetizer from nltk

and created a list from all the classes (tags)

```
`lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

intents = json.loads(open("intents.json").read())

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ["?", "!", ".", ","]

for intent in intents["intents"]:
    for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
        word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(word_list)
        documents.append(((word_list), intent["tag"]))
        if intent["tag"] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent["tag"])

words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignore_letters]
words = sorted(set(words))

classes = sorted(set(classes))

pickle.dump(words, open("trainingMenuAiWords.pkl", "wb"))
pickle.dump(classes, open("trainingMenuAiclasses.pkl", "wb"))`
```

then because i needed to feed the data somehow in to the model i created a list of 1s and 0s that responded to if a massage had a specefic token or not (1 if it had and 0 if it didn't)

```
`training = []
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)

for document in documents:
    bag = []
    word_patterns = document[0]
    word_patterns = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in word_patterns]
    for word in words:
        if word in word_patterns:
            bag.append(1)
        else:
            bag.append(0)
    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(document[1])] = 1
    training.append([bag, output_row])

random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training)`
```

and then i feed them to a nn model

```
`model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation="softmax"))

sgd = SGD(learning_rate=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=["accuracy"])
hist = model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=NUMBER_OF_TRAINING, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
model.save("menuAimodel.h5", hist)`
```

so the entire code for the training file is this :

```
`import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from time import perf_counter

from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.gradient_descent import SGD


NUMBER_OF_TRAINING = 3_000

start = perf_counter()

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

intents = json.loads(open("intents.json").read())

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ["?", "!", ".", ","]

for intent in intents["intents"]:
    for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
        word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(word_list)
        documents.append(((word_list), intent["tag"]))
        if intent["tag"] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent["tag"])

words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignore_letters]
words = sorted(set(words))

classes = sorted(set(classes))

pickle.dump(words, open("trainingMenuAiWords.pkl", "wb"))
pickle.dump(classes, open("trainingMenuAiclasses.pkl", "wb"))

training = []
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)

for document in documents:
    bag = []
    word_patterns = document[0]
    word_patterns = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in word_patterns]
    for word in words:
        if word in word_patterns:
            bag.append(1)
        else:
            bag.append(0)
    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(document[1])] = 1
    training.append([bag, output_row])

random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training)

train_x = list(training[:, 0])
train_y = list(training[:, 1])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation="softmax"))

sgd = SGD(learning_rate=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=["accuracy"])
hist = model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=NUMBER_OF_TRAINING, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
model.save("menuAimodel.h5", hist)


end = perf_counter()

print(f"training time in sec : {end - start}")
print(f"training time in min : {(end - start)/60}")

print("Done")`
```

now the problem is in this line where i try to create a numpy array with the list that contains those list of 1s and 0s it says they are not homogeneus but i dont undrstand why cuz in the code it checks for every token and add ether a 0 or a 1 so it shouldnt have any null value or longer or shorter list, in fact it was working just fine and i did created few test model with it but few days ago i changed to a conda virtual envorment to use my cuda cores and it stoped working i cant think of anything else that i changed, am i missing something ?

the line of code that gives the error

```
`training = np.array(training)`
```

and here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iparsw\Desktop\python learning\plotting\trainingMenuAi.py", line 60, in <module>
    training = np.array(training)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (554, 2) + inhomogeneous part.
```

i tried to check where did the list got inhomogeneous but i couldnt undrstand (im a ml newbie) and i tried to print it and check for inhomogeneous part by eye but the list got to big to fast and i wasnt able to find it

Answer (score 1):

i managed to fix the issue with changing

```
training = np.array(training)
```

to
training = np.array(training, dtype=object)

apparently its because i changed the numpy version im using

Comment: Thank you, I was running into the same issue!